# Set filter on XML parse in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How can I set a filter on my XML parse in objective-C?

This is my XML-file:

```
<shelters>
    <point id="1" lat="56.854643730" lon="9.476729748" sted="Jenle Plantage" postnr="0000" type="shelter" shelters="-" fire="Ja" wc="Nej" vand="Nej" pay="-" pafstand="-" note="Jenle Plantage" adr="Jenle Plantage" pic="nopic.png" />
    <point id="2" lat="55.253090091" lon="14.745165263" sted="Lejrplads Finnedalen" postnr="0000" type="shelter" shelters="-" fire="Ja" wc="Nej" vand="Nej" pay="-" pafstand="-" note="Lejrplads Finnedalen" adr="Lejrplads Finnedalen" pic="nopic.png" />
    <point id="3" lat="56.117966990" lon="9.463753344" sted="Løgager" postnr="0000" type="shelter" shelters="-" fire="Ja" wc="Nej" vand="Nej" pay="-" pafstand="-" note="Løgager" adr="Løgager" pic="nopic.png" />
    <point id="4" lat="55.028931084" lon="9.388940781" sted="Aabenraaskovene, Sønderskoven, Von Bergens Plads" postnr="0000" type="shelter" shelters="-" fire="Ja" wc="Nej" vand="Nej" pay="-" pafstand="-" note="Aabenraaskovene, Sønderskoven, Von Bergens Plads" adr="Aabenraaskovene, Sønderskoven, Von Bergens Plads" pic="nopic.png" />
    <point id="5" lat="56.126911668" lon="9.625711711" sted="Østre Gåsekær" postnr="0000" type="shelter" shelters="-" fire="Ja" wc="Nej" vand="Nej" pay="-" pafstand="-" note="Østre Gåsekær" adr="Østre Gåsekær" pic="nopic.png" />
</shelters>
```

And this is my parsing-section:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"shelters" ofType:@"xml"]];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:baseURL];

    [parser setDelegate:self.parserobj];

    BOOL success = [parser parse];

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.parserobj->annotations];
    self.isCurrentCoordinatesSet = false;
    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
```

I only want to get the items where

```
fire="Ja"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must basically implement `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` method of NSXMLParserDelegate, inside this delegate method you will copy the attribute dictionaries to an NSMutableArray like below:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

    if([[attributes valueForKey:@"fire"] isEquals:@"Ja"])
        [filteredElements addObject:attributes]; 
}
```

filteredElements must be declared as private variable/property and initialized before the call to [parser parse].

Comment: Nice snippet of code, but what do you mean by "class private variable"? A normal ivar would do, it seems to me.

Comment: I mean, a variable that you can declare at some scope to hold data during parsing and after parse finishes, I usually create a private ivar or property.

Comment: Fair enough, but that's an instance variable and not a class variable (which Objective-C doesn't really have).

Comment: This is my didStartElement section, where to put your code? I tried in the if-statement, but I get an error!

`- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"point"]) {
        
        // bla bla
        
    }

    element = [NSMutableString string];
}`

Comment: Inside the if block that is checking the elementName on which you will check for specific attribute value.

Comment: Woops, it works with: `if([elementName isEqualToString:@"point"] && [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] isEqual:@"24"]){ // bla }` - thanks:)

Comment: Another question, how do I do when I want to show items where `lat` is between 56.00000000 and 57.00000000.